# How to connect to TeamFoundationServer (tfs) using client api from a console application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I'm trying to connect to `TeamFoundationServer` hosted at visualstudio.com using its client API with a Console Application, but I get this error:

`TF400813: Resource not available for anonymous access. Client`

My code:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Uri collectionUri = new Uri("https://MyName.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection");

    TfsTeamProjectCollection collection =
        new TfsTeamProjectCollection(
            collectionUri,
            new System.Net.NetworkCredential(@"MeMail@gmail.com", "MyPassword"));

    WorkItemStore workItemStore = collection.GetService<WorkItemStore>(); 
}
```

Comment: What are those network credentials?  Is that a live id?

Comment: @EdwardThomson yes thats a live id

Comment: But I work with another tfs on our domain, and I couldn't connect to it to

Comment: What errors are you getting with *that*?

Comment: @EdwardThomson error: TF400813: Resource not available for anonymous access. Client

Comment: Is it working against `visualstudio.com`?  Can you paste an example of your code against the on-premises TFS server?

Answer (score 13):

You have to call the `EnsureAuthenticated()` method from `TfsTeamProjectCollection`:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Uri collectionUri = new Uri("https://MyName.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection");

    NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential("USERNAME", "PASSWORD");
    TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(collectionUri, credential);
    teamProjectCollection.EnsureAuthenticated();

    WorkItemStore workItemStore = teamProjectCollection.GetService<WorkItemStore>();

    WorkItemCollection workItemCollection = workItemStore.Query("QUERY HERE");

    foreach (var item in workItemCollection)
    {
        //Do something here.
    }
}
```

I hope it has solved your problem.

Comment: but where is authentication? I should login to tfs first by a `username` and `password`, that does not exist in your code

Comment: @OmidShariati I tried using the `System.Net.NetworkCredential` class but it opened a new window to authenticate in my TFS address (Microsoft's page). I'm using this way I answered you and it's working  for me without any credentials. Do you have more than one username to connector on your TFS?

Comment: @OmidShariati I just correct my answer. I put another way to connect using your credential.

Comment: I test it in a WindowsApplication, thats work, but it does not work on ConsoleApplication

Comment: @OmidShariati Could you try with the code corrected?

Comment: yeah I try that still not work. I get this error: `TF400813: Resource not available for anonymous access. Client '

Comment: `EnsureAuthenticated` is not necessary.  The only thing this method does is build a connection to the server if one doesn't exist so that end-users can call it to ensure a connection is possible.  In this case it is not helpful, since there is already code connecting (and failing).

Answer (score 4):

Set up [alternate credentials](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2013/01/07/how-to-connect-to-tf-service-without-a-prompt-for-liveid-credentials.aspx) for your account.  You can use alternate credentials for the command-line clients and as a `NetworkCredential` parameter.